# Socket.IO issue with illegal origin?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using :
"socket.io": "~0.9.10"

I am running into this issue when I go to my apache webserver hosted client.html page hosted on port 80:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5000/socket.io/1/?t=1348624895534. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I am running SocketIO on my serverside to be on port 5000 as shown below:

```
io = io.listen(5000);
io.set("origins","*");
```

However, everytime I load my apache client.html page, I see in my SocketIO server console:

```
warn: illegal origin: http://localhost
```

How do I get rid of this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

The error you are getting comes from the fact that Socket.IO seems to be using XHR rather that Websockets. This is what socket.IO does when websockets are not available it uses another protocol, FlashSockets, XHR-polling... etc.

You need to set a header on you apache server to allow a query to be made to another website, here your Socket.io server.

Here is a [how to](http://enable-cors.org/#how-apache).

It would be a lot simpler for you if you just used only one server.
You could use Express to deliver the static html file. [Here](https://github.com/dotcloud/socket.io-on-dotcloud) is a demo/tutorial app to get started easily with Socket.IO + Express.

This demo is a [boiler plate](http://deploy.dotcloud.com/Node.js/Socket.IO/1) to push on dotCloud, so if you want to painlessly deploy, follow those instructions.

Comment: Not exactly clear... I am running Windows a2enmod is an unknown command. Is the "Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *" something you put in a specific area of the httpd.conf? If so, where specifically? Does not seem obvious. What I have done so far is uncomment the line "LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so" in the httpd.conf, but do not know where to go from here.

Comment: a2enmod is a tool to enable an apache 2 module. Do you have a reason to use Apache + Node, rather than just Node with Express and Socket.IO (they play well together). Because if not it would make your life so much easier.

Comment: Otherwise to activate an Apache module on windows simply open `conf/httpd.conf` from your Apache install folder and un comment the line `#LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so` to `LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so`

Comment: The issue is the html files I have use a lot of external javascript i.e. jquery. The sample you show above, there are no more .html files, instead I'd have to rewrite all my normal .html files to the ".jade" templating language.

Comment: I have uncommented out the part you mentioned, though do not know where to insert the line "Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *" within the httpd.conf file.

Comment: You don't have to use jade just put you file in the public folder and they will be deliver as they are, right at your server's root.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` header to `'*'`

```
response.writeHead(200, {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
});
```

Comment: How and where do I do this? I was under the impression that the io.set("origins","*"); would have taken care of it. Nowhere appears to have any documentation on how to set this. I am using express 3.x.

Comment: I am not sure where the "response" variable is coming from as currently I have pretty much the same code as shown here: http://socket.io/. Are you implying that I should be sticking that io.sockets.io within a "route" in express so that I have access to the response variable?

Comment: I didn't see that you were using apache. My updated answer was for node.js server. Anyway for apache set `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *` in config file